# How do I add .jpf mime type to config.php?

Tags: image

In order to upload JPEG2000 (.jpf) images to a site I need to add a new mime type to config.php. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration override you can use here:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/system-configuration-overrides.html#mime_whitelist_additions

Just use that in your config file to add your custom mime types to the whitelist.

Comment: When I add this I still get a File not allowed error: $config['mime_whitelist_additions'] = array('image/vnd.adobe.photoshop');

Comment: I doubt "image/vnd.adobe.photoshop" is the mime type for a JPEG2000 file. You'll have to look up the correct mime type string to white list.

Comment: Hence my question. I have not been able to find anything on that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_2000
Right in the wiki page, **image/jp2**

Comment: Tried this: $config['mime_whitelist_additions'] = array('image/jp2'); Error persists.

Comment: Did you try the other available mime type strings on the wiki page? One of them might work. Also, why don't you use a mime type checker on an example file you want to upload and get the mime type string from that?

Comment: Mime type checker says image/jp2, so I am not sure what steps to take from here. Thanks for trying.